# How to Trigger WebdriverIo framework locally (Source Code) within Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, webdriver-io

How to Trigger WebdriverIo framework locally (Source Code) within Jenkins?

I'm able to trigger and target the wdio file (Triggering automation tests) if I upload the project to Git using Jenkins: 'Source Code Management' > Git and then point to the repository but is there a way to target and execute my project locally by pointing to the local framework folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under build section in Jenkins, you can provide the below command-

```
cd <your_workspace>\node_modules\.bin
```

And then provide your wdio command to execute tests. It should work.
You can refer to my article [here](https://medium.com/@aparna.gopalakrishnan/10-easy-steps-to-facilitate-how-to-execute-local-tests-through-jenkins-913bd7d32270) for more info.